# Java AndroidStudio - BottomSheetDialog Image Overflowing bug

Tags: java, android, android-bottomsheetdialog

i have problem with my BottomSheetDialog, i want to put my image on the cardview of BottomSheetDialog, that work in AndroidStudio Design editor but not in my device. Do you have any solution ?

[Bug Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmPau.png)

These are my results on this picture

- left -> Android Studio Design Editor (All work)
- center -> Result in device (`card_view:cardElevation="0dp"` didn't work and white background behind)
- right -> My Wish on Figma (*Exemple image*)

I want to remove this white background and put image on the top

xml code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_character_menu_bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/secondary"
            card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_marginStart="140dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Lorem ipsum"
                            android:textColor="@color/secondary_font"
                            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />

                        <FrameLayout
                            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="2dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                            android:alpha="0.05"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_character_bottom_sheet_rename"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingStart="32dp"
                    android:padding="8dp">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="32dp"
                        android:layout_height="32dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_edit_line"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/secondary_font"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:text="Rename"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_character_bottom_sheet_edit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingStart="32dp"
                    android:padding="8dp">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="32dp"
                        android:layout_height="32dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_round_edit"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/secondary_font"
                        android:text="Edit"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_character_bottom_sheet_share"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingStart="32dp"
                    android:padding="8dp">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="32dp"
                        android:layout_height="32dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_share"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/secondary_font"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:text="Share"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_character_bottom_sheet_delete"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingStart="32dp"
                    android:padding="8dp">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="32dp"
                        android:layout_height="32dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_trashcan_solid"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/secondary_font"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                        android:text="Delete"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="128dp"
            android:layout_height="128dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:strokeWidth="4dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ImageView.Corner.Round"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and how I Implement it:

```
BottomSheetDialog mBottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(mMainActivity);
View sheetView = mMainActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_character_bottom_sheet, null);
mBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(sheetView);
mBottomSheetDialog.show();
```

Thanks for all tips and idea to help me.

[Edit] I have solve my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77202147/22654090
but if anyone know how to put border of image to transparent can say to me

Comment: What device you are using? Emulator or Physical and which model?

Comment: I use physical Huawei p smart 2020 with android version 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem!
I simply created a custom style for the BottomSheetDialog to remove the white background:

```
BottomSheetDialog mBottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(mMainActivity, R.style.SheetDialog);
```

```xml
<style name="SheetDialog" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.3</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
</style>
```

and added elevation to my image to put it on top of the cardview

```xml
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="128dp"
            android:layout_height="128dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:strokeWidth="4dp"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ImageView.Corner.Round"
            />
```

Goodbye !